INA228 trouble with i2c connection when monitoring high dI/dt
I'm in the process of evaluating the INA228 as a precision current monitor for my application using Adafruit's neat board. Interfacing using a Raspberry Pi Pico and MicroPython. Everything works great when initially testing at 5 V and switching to a load consuming 50 mA.
Moved the dev board over to my main project which is a MOSFET driven 48 V system switching ~10 amps, and then I started receiving EIO errors in the Pico console and my program crashed. I added an inline 20 ohm resistor to get the current down to ~2 A and the system would still crash with an I2C EIO error when reading the current register. I then connected the breakout board to my bench PSU and ramped the current up to a few amps and the sensor was fine giving consistent continuous readings. I then managed to reproduce the crash by sparking the connectors from the power supply, so it looks like something coming from the fast switching of the MOSFETs. Then, as another test, I initialised the INA228 in shutdown and then read the current register every ms, and it just outputs a static junk number from the register, and the MOSFET switched current through the shunt which is not even being looked at by the ADC still causes the I2C connection to bug out. I then slowed the I2C connection to 100 kHz and I still see errors. Checked the PU resistors on data and clock, and they are solid external 4k7 connections to 3v3. Definitely looks like a problem induced by a high dI/dt.
Where I'm at now is reading that register in a try catch loop, so the INA228 is not resetting or anything wild. It's workable (perhaps with sample and hold on the microcontroller) but annoying. The plot below shows serial monitor output of current into a resistive load. The MOSFET is full on for 40 ms or so and then moves into a PWM phase which the INA228 is integrating over to form a lower average. All those dips to zero are register reading failures. Any ideas what could be happening here?

Adafruit made their schematics available here, although they are in Eagle CAD format. I have requested a simple image file.
Update:
Going deeper, tech support at Adafruit gave me this:

This is interesting because the INA228 datasheet states

In applications that do not have large energy storage, electrolytic capacitors on one or both sides of the shunt,
an input overstress condition may result from an excessive dV/dt of the voltage applied to the input. A hard
physical short is the most likely cause of this event. This problem occurs because an excessive dV/dt can
activate the ESD protection in the device in systems where large currents are available. Testing demonstrates
that the addition of 10-Ω resistors in series with each input of the device sufficiently protects the inputs against
this dV/dt failure up to the 40-V maximum differential voltage rating of the device. Selecting these resistors in the
range noted has minimal effect on accuracy. Do not use values greater than 100 ohms for RFILTER. Doing so will degrade gain error and increase nonlinearity.


So in this knowledge and seeing the dev board has none of the input filtering that would be required by my application, I quickly put something together, moving the shunt from the dev board and putting some input filtering behind it using minimum values of 10 ohm and 100nF

And then assembled it to the pico board getting rid of the i2c wires entirely to remove another variable

Unfortunately, this still results in flaky memory reads under high current. So I went a step further and neatened everything using higher values of 68 ohm input resistors and a 1uF electrolytic in the filter stage . .

And I still see the same (quasi-periodic) drop outs in the readings, i.e. memory reads giving i2c errors from micropython on the pico, but only under high dI/dt conditions. I'm lost again. Any suggestions for where to explore next greatly received.

"which the INA228 is integrating" ... are you sure about that? Can you share a schematic too?

The schematic for the breakout board is now linked. If the ADC wasn't integrating, you'd see the individual PWM pulses after the initial pulse, so I'm pretty sure about that part. That's not so relevant because I get memory reading errors with the device in shutdown mode also as mentioned.
